# Result is not display in autocomplete (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I use ng-prime `<p-autocomplete>` for display values via search in the back-end

here is my html

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="agent" [suggestions]="filteredAgents" name="agents" (completeMethod)="filterAgents($event)"  [size]="10"
                    placeholder="Agents" [minLength]="3"></p-autoComplete>
```

At the component.ts I initialize array like this at start of the component

```
filteredAgents: string[] = [];
```

and I have a method to send query to back end and push it to array

```
 filterAgents(event) {
    let query = event.query;
    this._agentsService.getAgentSearch(query).subscribe(result => {
      result.items.forEach((value) => {
            this.filteredAgents.push(value.name);
            console.log(this.filteredAgents);
       });
    });
}
```

I see filtered value in console, but I don't see it in suggestions.

Where can be my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoComplete either uses setter based checking or ngDoCheck to realize if the suggestions has changed to update the UI. This is configured using the immutable property, when enabled (default) setter based detection is utilized so your changes such as adding or removing a record should always create a new array reference instead of manipulating an existing array as Angular does not trigger setters if the reference does not change. ( Angular documentation )

Array.prototype.push doesnt create a new reference it rather mutates the original array. So you need to make a new one.

```
 filterAgents(event) {
    let query = event.query;
    this._agentsService.getAgentSearch(query).subscribe(result => {
            this.filteredAgents = [...result.items.map(e => e.name)]
        });
    }
```

I maped the result to extract the names.

Comment: One problem

value has type `value: SearchAgentOutputDto`

So code will show exception map is not exists in type

`filterAgents(event) {
        let query = event.query;
        this._agentsService.getAgentSearch(query).subscribe(result => {
          result.items.forEach((value) => {
                this.filteredAgents = [value.map(e => e.name)];
           });
        });
    }`

Comment: The problem is that he is mutating the array not making a new one, so he just need to make a new array and place it in the filteredAgents variable.

Comment: Dude. thats super ! It helps

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped! :)

Comment: One more little question.
If I need to map e.name and e.id (two values)

How I need to write .map?
I guess I need dataKey for id value and field for name in autocomplete?

Comment: For example with push I can do it like this
`.push({ field: value.name, dataKey: value.id });`

Comment: this.filteredAgents = [...result.items.map(e => {let obj = {field:e.name, dataKey:e.id}; return obj})]

Answer (score 0):

If filtered agents is an object array try adding field="name" to the directive attributes.

Here name is a field in the object. The directive uses this field to display in suggestions

Comment: This not helps (